Rails 7.2 breaks find_by with symbol
I'm upgrading a Rails app from 7.1.3.2 to 7.2.1,, and I'm facing an issue with find_by.
In my controller, I have
ControlPlan.find_by("code = :code AND validity_dates @> date :date",
                    code: hash_params[:control_plan_code],
                    date: hash_params[:inspection_started_on])

Which worked fine in 7.1.3.2 but generates an error after the upgrade. The issue is related to the interpolation of validity_dates.
As shown below in the console, if I use a string for the date, the query works but if I use a symbol, I got an error even if the SQL produced looks identical.
s(dev)> ControlPlan.where("validity_dates @> date '2020-12-24'").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"control_plans\".* FROM \"control_plans\" WHERE (validity_dates @> date '2020-12-24')"
s(dev)> ControlPlan.where("validity_dates @> date '2020-12-24'")
  ControlPlan Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "control_plans".* FROM "control_plans" WHERE (validity_dates @> date '2020-12-24') /* loading for pp */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> []
s(dev)> ControlPlan.where("validity_dates @> date :date", date: "2020-12-24").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"control_plans\".* FROM \"control_plans\" WHERE (validity_dates @> date '2020-12-24')"
s(dev)> ControlPlan.where("validity_dates @> date :date", date: "2020-12-24")
An error occurred when inspecting the object: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:"PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"$1\"\nLINE 1: ...ROM \"control_plans\" WHERE (validity_dates @> date $1) /* loa...\n                                                             ^\n">
Result of Kernel#inspect: #<ControlPlan::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000010c1685c0 @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer), @table=#<Arel::Table:0x000000010d883340 @name="control_plans", @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer), @type_caster=#<ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:0x000000010daa7bf8 @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer)>, @table_alias=nil>, @values={:where=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation::WhereClause:0x000000010cfabf38 @predicates=[#<Arel::Nodes::BoundSqlLiteral "(validity_dates @> date :date)" {:date=>"2020-12-24"}>]>}, @loaded=nil, @predicate_builder=#<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder:0x000000010da85da0 @table=#<ActiveRecord::TableMetadata:0x000000010da85e90 @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer), @arel_table=#<Arel::Table:0x000000010d883340 @name="control_plans", @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer), @type_caster=#<ActiveRecord::TypeCaster::Map:0x000000010daa7bf8 @klass=ControlPlan(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, validity_dates: daterange, code: integer, state: enum, edition: integer)>, @table_alias=nil>, @reflection=nil>, @handlers=[[Set, #<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler:0x000000010da85328 @predicate_builder=#<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder:0x000000010da85da0 ...>>], [Array, #<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::ArrayHandler:0x000000010da854b8 @predicate_builder=#<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder:0x000000010da85da0 ...>>], [ActiveRecord::Relation, #<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::RelationHandler:0x000000010da85738>], [Range, #<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::RangeHandler:0x000000010da85828 @predicate_builder=#<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder:0x000000010da85da0 ...>>], [BasicObject, #<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder::BasicObjectHandler:0x000000010da85cb0 @predicate_builder=#<ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder:0x000000010da85da0 ...>>]]>, @delegate_to_klass=false, @future_result=nil, @records=nil, @async=false, @none=false, @should_eager_load=nil, @arel=nil, @to_sql=nil, @take=nil, @offsets=nil, @cache_keys=nil, @cache_versions=nil>

I checked the Rails 7.2 release notes, but I found nothing about this.
I could make it work updating my code as below, but I'd rather keeping it as it's now.
ControlPlan.find_by("code = :code AND validity_dates @> date '#{hash_params[:inspection_started_on]}'",
                    code: hash_params[:control_plan_code])

What am I missing here?

Seems this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e6a5deca626c944933211d7977f4e7e76869e74 is causing your issue. Rather than quoting through the connection it binds as a SqlLiteral. You could probably solve this using, "code = :code AND validity_dates @> date ':date'" or we can build some Arel.

@engineersmnky, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I get the same error.

Hmm. What happens if you try using date: Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(hash_params[:inspection_started_on]) as part of the argument Hash?  If that doesn't work we could make an ugly mess of this using something like where(code: hash_params[:control_plan_code]).where(Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('@>',ControlPlan.arel_table[:validity_dates], Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation('date',Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(hash_params[:inspection_started_on]))))

The Arel::Nodes.build_quoted did the trick. Thanks again.

@Sig please post the solution as an actual answer, for others to benefit.

@Greg See below.

ControlPlan.find_by("code = :code AND validity_dates @> date :date",
                    code: hash_params[:control_plan_code],
                    date: Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(hash_params[:inspection_started_on]))

